# SP3 installed, vs. SP3 slipstreamed, difference in default security settings?

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, sametime

A Lotus Notes installation, Domino 7x, which ends up trying to start a IBM SameTime 7.5.1 chat client, fails on some machines.

Specifically, it fails on Windows XP machines that has SP3 slipstreamed, whereas Windows XP machines which has had SP3 installed afterwards, works fine.

The problem can be worked around temporarily by adjusting the advanced settings in Internet Explorer, related to Active Content:

```
[ ] Allow active content from CDs to run on My Computer
```

Setting that `[x]` there makes the whole thing work, removing it (which is the default setting), makes it not work. But as I said, this setting is disabled on the machines that had SP3 installed afterwards, and it works there.

This isn't an acceptable solution, so we need to figure out the root cause of this.

What happens is that as part of the initialization process, Lotus Notes downloads a small web page. This web page contains javascript, that simply runs window.open with an url that points to the SameTime server, including session id, etc.

If I take this url, and pastes it into the address bar in Notes, everything works exactly as expected.

As such, I believe that the problem is somehow related to Notes not allowing the script to run at all.

Process Monitor shows that Notes does not do any sort of network query against that server after the web page was downloaded (I can see the point where it is written to disk), so I believe the problem is with the javascript handling.

So, the questions:

- Does anyone know of any specific security differences between installing SP3, and slipstreaming SP3, that could impact this?
- Does anyone have any other ideas for what specifically we can try to adjust on the machine in order to get this working?

Comment: either it's a bug, or a 20000 rep user confused stackoverflow with serverfault ;)

Comment: Since the problem seems to be that Domino doesn't run the javascript properly, I figured Stack Overflow with its smart people ;) could try to tackle the problem first :)

Comment: moving it to ServerFault, probably where it belongs, doesn't look like it's a javascript problem, more like a security setting.